# how does selenium web driver work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am trying to scrap a website so I use selenium-webdriver. 
I've chosen javascript and nodejs as language to teach myself. 
The following is a very basic code to understand the behaviour of the tool.

I launch it with the following command line : 
    node  --debug-brk=5858 src/app.js

```
 var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

 var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();

    driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    debugger;
    driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
    driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
    driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
    driver.quit();
```

I am using vscode as IDE.
When I press F5, after setting a breakpoint in the code, the breakpoint is hit BUT no browser is opened yet. I click on resume (in VScode), the script finishes, and **only then** the browser is launched and corresponding commands are executed, my breakpoint being now ignored since it has already been hit.

This has the following consequence : I cannot step by step the selenium webdriver and thus am unable to evaluate the content of a find elements with xpath command.

I am missing Something but fail to see what.
Do I have to add Sleep statements ?

I've seen most people use java but I'd rather stick to javascript if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues that I can see in your program.

1. When using javascript to program webdriver, an important concept is that all function calls are asynchronous and return a `Thenable` or `Promise`. So you cannot write line by line like in sequential programming.

   You need to work this way:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver')
       .then( function(){
           driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
           ...
       });
   ```

   See WebDriver's javascript API Documentation here: 
   https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index.html
2. In terms of debugging, if you pause in the browser's developer tool and trace there, what you trace is the website program that you are trying to scrape, but not your webdriver program. I use WebStorm to trace my webdriver program.

Comment: I know selenium works with promises, but as described here : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs, you don't need the ".then" anymore. I use vsocde for now and cannot debug the webdriver program. currently, I do node --debug-brk but this does not enable me to debug.